# Insert a picture on the top of each page in an OpenXML document

Tags: c#, .net, openxml, openxml-sdk

I am creating OpenXML documents in C# for Word and I find always that it's not possible to determine where a page break will appears in the document. This creates the following problem:

I want to insert on the top of each page a little image, which gives a little overview of the elements of the page.

To that effect, is it possible to use conditions such as:

"`if(page break reached == true)` then insert a little image on the next page"?

I could use this condition after each paragraph, so I do not have to know where a page break appears. Any other solutions would also help.

Comment: Or put the image in the header, the header HAS to appear at the top of each page

Comment: each image has specific informations about the elements of the page, so the images are different from page to page.

Comment: you can have different images in different headers

Answer (score 0):

Word documents are not paginated in the file format. The only way to determine to what objects are on what page is to use a rendering engine. Aspose.Words is one example but it's not cheap.

Another option is to add a header and put the image there or use a watermark

Answer (score 0):

You can workaround your issue by manually inserting a page break whenever you want to insert an image, page break in xml,

```
 <w:r>
      <w:br w:type="page" />
 </w:r>
```

You also need to add [`lastRenderedPageBreak`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.lastrenderedpagebreak.aspx) element before the content in your next page,

```
  <w:r>
    <w:lastRenderedPageBreak />
    <w:t>your content on page 2</w:t>
  </w:r>
```

The same thing can be acheived in code as:

```
    Run run1 = new Run();
    Break break1 = new Break(){ Type = BreakValues.Page }; //Breaks page
    run1.Append(break1); //append your run to paragraph on page 1
```

on page 2

```
    Run run2 = new Run();
    LastRenderedPageBreak lastRenderedPageBreak1 = new LastRenderedPageBreak();
    //add your image here in openxml code
    run2.Append(lastRenderedPageBreak1);
```